# Scaling the texture in (py)bullet

Tags: python, bulletphysics, bullet

I'm using pybullet (which is a python wrapper over [bullet](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3)
 to render a couple of 3d object (with no links,
 just regular bodies). I have some textures that I'd like to put (when loading urdf file) on them. I learned that the place where the texture is defined is an [mtl file](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/).

But, when I just substitute the argument of `map_Kd`, I'm getting the repeated pattern of the texture, as in the image:
[image: repeated pattern]

It seems, mtl format supports scaling of the texture with the parameter `-s`, but when I added it I got some errors within the [examples/Importers/ImportMeshUtility/b3ImportMeshUtility.cpp](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/Importers/ImportMeshUtility/b3ImportMeshUtility.cpp).

Is there a way to "stretch" the texture in bullet to cover the whole object or decide on the scaling of it?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to use Bullet (physics engines) to do 3D rendering?

Comment: It has a convenient, python api and is somewhat well documented. Any good alternatives?

Comment: Thank.  I don't know about library for python though. (If it was C++, Ogre is nice.)

Comment: You may be interested in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)'s game-engine.  I found a [link](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?364762-Python-Tutorial-for-Beginning-Programmers-in-the-Blender-Game-Engine) to some Python tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to 'stretch' the texture, you have to modify the UV values in the Wavefront .obj file. You can use Blender to load the .obj file, scale the UV coordinates and save the .obj file. At the moment there is no texture scaling through .mtl file settings in pybullet. If you still want it, just file a feature request in the Bullet issue tracker at http://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3

Further documentation in http://pybullet.org.